# How to add a CSS-File to a JavaFX Scene without FXML?

Tags: javafx

I need to add a CSS-file to the Main Scene. It's a first year JavaFX project and we can't use FXML, so this is the only way I know how to navigate between different forms, any other suggestions as on how to switch between JavaFX classes would be appreciated.

```
package javalearningcurve;


import javafx.geometry.HPos;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.FontWeight;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author Conor
 */
public class MainMenu extends Stage {

    GridPane grid = new GridPane();

    Text scenetitle = new Text("Main Menu");
    Button btnQuiz = new Button("New Quiz");
    Button btnViewResults = new Button("View Results");
    Button btnLogout = new Button("Logout");
    Button btnQuit = new Button("Quit");
    HBox hbBtn = new HBox();


    MainMenu() {
        this.setTitle("Main Menu");
        grid.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_CENTER);
        grid.setHgap(10);
        grid.setVgap(10);

        grid.setPadding(new Insets(10,25,25,25));

        scenetitle.setFont(Font.font("Tahoma", FontWeight.BOLD, 20));
        scenetitle.setFill(Color.RED);
        grid.setHalignment(scenetitle, HPos.CENTER);

        hbBtn.setPrefWidth(200);
        hbBtn.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        btnQuiz.setMinWidth(hbBtn.getPrefWidth());
        btnViewResults.setMinWidth(hbBtn.getPrefWidth());
        btnLogout.setMinWidth(hbBtn.getPrefWidth());
        btnQuit.setMinWidth(hbBtn.getPrefWidth());

        grid.add(scenetitle, 0, 2, 2, 1);
        grid.add(btnQuiz, 0, 3);
        grid.add(btnViewResults,0 , 4);
        grid.add(btnLogout,0 , 5);
        grid.add(btnQuit,0 , 6);

        //primaryStage.show();
        this.setScene(new Scene(grid, 400, 275));
        this.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("/stylesheet.css").toExternalForm());`

So basically, instead of `this.setScene(new Scene(grid, 400, 275));` do this:

```
Scene scene = new Scene(grid, 400, 275);
scene.getStylesheets().add(this.getClass().getResource("/stylesheet.css").toExternalForm());
this.setScene(scene);
```